# как нажать на кнопку сообщения через pyrogram от лица пользователя

Tags: python, pyrogram

мне для абуза одного из телеграм ботов нужно нажать на кнопку отправляемого им сообщения. я уже разобрался как можно боту отправлять сообщения но не могу понять как можно имитировать нажатие на кнопку. как это можно сделать используя pyrogram имея айди сообщения можно нажать на кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен метод Message.click():

```
message.click(0) # Нажимаем по первой кнопке
# Да, все так просто ;)
```

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.click